# opencv bot Recursion Error using pyautogui , python-imagesearch, cv2

Tags: python, opencv, for-loop, bots, pyautogui

Im writing a bot using cv2 , pyautogui,and imagesearch libaries. in this function im searching for an image then I'm going to run another function when found if not search again.

I get an error if the image is not found and the function runs for a while. can anyone help me without setting the recursion higher?
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object. if I'm unclear tell me don't just -1 me please and I will re-explain

(pip install python-imagesearch. it's a wrapper around pyautogui and opencv2, to allow you to easily add cross-platform image searching capabilities to your project. https://pypi.org/project/python-imagesearch/ or https://github.com/drov0/python-imagesearch)

```
from python_imagesearch.imagesearch import *
    
def function_one():
    pos = imagesearch("Bot/image1.png")
    if pos[0] != -1:
        print("found image one")
        function_two()
        print('running action two')
        function_three()
    else:
        print("didn't find image one, starting again")
        function_one()
```

Answer (score -1):

this is wanted to avoid but it worked good

```
import sys

sys.setrecursionlimit(1500)
```